# Delete Orphans in HABTM ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class Actor < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_and_belongs_to_many :movies

  before_destroy :remove_orphaned_initialize
  after_destroy :remove_orphaned


private

  def remove_orphaned_initialize
    @instvariable = self.movies
  end

  def remove_orphaned
    @instvariable.each do |m|
      m.destroy if m.actors.empty? and m.titles.empty?  ##movies also have habtm with Title
    end
  end

end
```

if i delete an actor record
then the orphan movie is not deleted because the @instvariable is nil in remove_orphaned

could you explain how i could achieve it.

if i try to cal remove_orphaned before destroy , then m.actors wil never be empty..
coz the present doctor instance is not yet deleted

Comment: why don't you use the around callback `around_destroy` (see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#destroying-an-object)

Comment: i tried using around_destroy just now..there is no error but actor instance itself is not getting destroyed and the condition m.actors.empty? is false so orphaned movie is also not getting destroyed

Comment: Rails does this for you. Just use `has_many` with `dependent: :destroy`.

Comment: im using "has and belongs to many".. cause actors can act in many movies and  movie can contain many actors..

Answer (score 0):

This is problematic because a movie without any actors is not an orphan, it's a childless parent. If it's problematic to have a movie without a child then it's not logically possible to create the movie prior to linking it to an actor.

Maybe you could do something based on a counter_cache in the movie to store the number of actors related to it, and have an after_update callback on the movie such that if the counter cache is set to zero then delete the movie. Not sure if changes to counter_cache values trigger an after_update callback though.

Sounds like a strange situation though.

Comment: here since im using many to many, parent-child are interchangeable words i think..so i used orphans..
Yes u r right regarding the logic..
actually i just wanted to prevent the orphans by taking care  while destroying associated objects and not implement constraints while creating..

is there possiblity of just geting the array of results of self.movies and save in instance variable,
so that i can destroy those..

ill also take a look into counter_cache

Comment: There's still an intersection table between the two models, and that is actually the child of both. The actor and movie models are parents of it.